# Next.js restricted pages and user authentication best practices

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, jwt

I'm building a user login from scratch on Next.js on the frontend. How the authentication is currently working is this:

1. On the login page, a request is being sent to the login API endpoint with email/password for validation
2. If it validates, it responds with a JSON object which includes the JWT token data and refresh token (as a httponly cookie)
3. On the front end, the JWT token is saved in the application state

When I'm on a restricted page which should only be accessible when a user is logged in, it is checking whether the token exists. This works, but I realise that it would be easy for the user to update this state manually via JS, meaning they would get access to the restricted page.

My question is this: what is the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: Is the JWT used for authenticating requests against the API? Is the JWT symmetric or asymmetric?

Comment: Hey Cameron, I think it's asymmetric. Yes exactly, it's used to authenticate requests against the API

Comment: You have 3 options: read the JWK without validating & check it hasn't expired, use the public key to validate the signature & check it isn't expired or check it exists then hit when an endpoint to confirm with your server it is valid. I'd personally check it exists, check it's not expired and then validate when you hit an endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Add your validation logic to a middleware (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware).

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

    if (!validated ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect("/auth/signin")
    } 

    return NextResponse.next()
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: '/about/:path*',
}
```